# Extract key value with jq if key name matches 'Name'

Tags: json, select, key, jq, aws-cli

I need to extract a key value with jq, only if key name is `Name`. Below is an example. I have some AMI's that don't have a key name of `Name` and I want to ignore them.

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-id snap-123 --region eu-west-1 --profile myprofile
{
    "Snapshots": [
        {
            "Description": "AMI upgrader",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "AMI upgrader",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "Encrypted": false,
            "VolumeId": "vol-9356e811",
            "State": "completed",
            "VolumeSize": 20,
            "StartTime": "2018-05-31T13:58:31.000Z",
            "Progress": "100%",
            "OwnerId": "1234",
            "SnapshotId": "snap-1234"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried;

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-id snap-123 --region eu-west-1 --profile myprofile | jq -r '.Snapshots[].Tags[]|.Name?.Value'
```

But it returns `null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `select`:

```
jq -r '.Snapshots[].Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name").Value'
```